# Enthusiast/Fanatic Badge - Do We Need to Just Visit or Participate?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, activity-badges

To obtain the Enthusiast or Fanatic badge, do we just need to visit while logged in each day or do we also have to have some activity (such as editing, answering, asking, commenting, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <strike>current</strike> former accepted answer to this question is wrong, although it is likely that it was correct at the time it was written. See Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485).