# What counts as a visit to Stackoverflow for a given day?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enthusiast/Fanatic Badge - Do We Need to Just Visit or Participate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29303/enthusiast-fanatic-badge-do-we-need-to-just-visit-or-participate)
>   [Is there a minimum level of activity required to get the “Enthusiast” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/is-there-a-minimum-level-of-activity-required-to-get-the-enthusiast-badge)
>   [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

I'm on my way to getting the [`Fanatic`](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic) badge (currently at 87 days) and I'm a little worried that I may miss a day somewhere and get reset.

A while back I was sitting on about 55-60 days and even though I had navigated to Stackoverflow on my iPhone over the weekend, the counter seemed to have reset. This was pretty disappointing at the time, so I've been sure to browse through at least 3-5 pages each day to be certain that a visit is counted.

On the weekends I don't have access to a PC so I do this via iPhone.

So the question is: what do I need to do to ensure a visit is counted for that day? Is it as simple as loading the homepage while logged in and I just got unlucky somehow or is there something different that triggers this?

Comment: I believe you have to visit a real page, i.e., not the homepage (and maybe your profile?).  Logging in isn't enough IIRC.  This is a dupe but I'm not sure where the older question is :P

Comment: @MatthewRead Cheers, I had a quick flick through the similar questions dialogue but couldn't see anything so I gave it a go anyways.

Comment: The one I was thinking of with the actual answer (thanks @ChrisF): [Consecutive days problem #97?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

Comment: Those answer my question. I'd close mine but I don't have enough rep - thanks.

Comment: Just visiting is OK. But SO defines a day using UTC, and not your local time zone.