# Tracking Time for certain badges

Tags: discussion, badges, consecutive-days

There are some badges which track your presence on the particular stack - [enthusiast](/questions/tagged/enthusiast) and [fanatic](/questions/tagged/fanatic) are the two that come to mind that appear to be available on all stacks with consistent criteria (30 consecutive days visit, and 100 consecutive days visit, respectively). However, it seems that tracking your "appearances" on these badges is inconsistent - for example, in spite of visiting all of my (other) stacks on Saturday, some of my stacks - Retrocomputing, for example - did not increment, and when I did not visit at all on Sunday, some of my stacks - StackOverflow, for example - did not reset to zero.

How does the SE network track this, and how can I ensure that a visit to a particular stack is recognized - or that a failure to visit is recognized?

*Note: the [Consecutive-Days-Problem-#97](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97) is accepted as an explanation for the resets from Saturday - but it doesn't explain why they didn't **all** reset on Sunday, when I didn't visit the SE Network at all.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97) and [enthusiast-fanatic-badge do-we-need-to-just-visit-or-participate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29303/enthusiast-fanatic-badge-do-we-need-to-just-visit-or-participate)

Comment: @Yaron - I'm a bit surprised that https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97 didn't come up when I was entering the question - or that my SE-search-foo didn't catch it either - but yeah, I'll grant that as a duplicate for counting why some of my stacks reset after Saturday - but it doesn't explain why they didn't _all_ reset after Sunday, when I definitely did _not_ visit _any_ pages anywhere on the SE network.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin are you sure that you didn't just do more on some sites, maybe vote on something or view for questions? The dupe I linked explained just visiting a site isn't enough but the exact rules aren't published. That's remembering it's in UTC time so some views may have been either side of the day.

Comment: @PeterJ - Looked at the lists of questions, not at any particular question on the reset stacks from Saturday, which is why I accept the Consecutive Days question as an explanation for the Saturday resets - but it doesn't explain the _failure_ to globally reset when I didn't visit _anything_ at all on _Sunday_.

Comment: @Jeff, so when you say you didn't visit Sunday does that include after 8:00PM Saturday night? Because if you're in NY that's Sunday UTC.

Comment: @PeterJ - That's correct - my last visit was actually during NYC midafternoon, as I recall, on Saturday; Saturday night, I went to dinner with my parents at 7 local time, and did not get home until after 9 local time - so no visit after 00:00 UTC. And nothing on Sunday local time at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know exactly when the 24 hours window start/end.

It is possible to visit the site two times with a gap of 47 hours and 59 minutes, and still visit the site in two consecutive days.

This can happen if you visit the site on the first minute of the first day and on the last minute of the next day.

Comment: OK, so, just to clarify: It's not the time lapse between my visits that count, it's the UCT date/time of the two consecutive visits that is the determinant factor.